# Clojure merge list of maps based on keys

Tags: merge, clojure, group-by, reduce

I need to convert the following data:

```
[{["A" 1] [{:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15}], ["A" 2] [{:ms "A", :s 2, :v 18}], ["A" 4] [{:ms "A", :s 4, :v 19}]}
 {["A" 1] [{:ms "A", :s 1, :v2 5}], ["A" 2] [{:ms "A", :s 2, :v2 8}], ["B" 4] [{:ms "B", :s 4, :v2 9}]}]
```

to:

```
[{:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15, :v2 5} {:ms "A", :s 2, :v 18, :v2 8} {:ms "A", :s 4, :v 19} {:ms "B", :s 4, :v2 9}]
```

I'm struggling with the implementation, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I got 99% of an answer written, then I realized that your last two maps break the pattern. Here's what I had written as an answer: https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/d5c766a0407def6ac81cb6775212b12e Note how the end result isn't quite correct. Not sure how to overcome this (too early :/). Hopefully someone can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: something like this should work: `(map (partial apply merge) (vals (apply merge-with concat data)))` => `({:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15, :v2 5} {:ms "A", :s 2, :v 18, :v2 8} {:ms "A", :s 4, :v 19} {:ms "B", :s 4, :v2 9})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would work:

```
(def data [{["A" 1] [{:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15}],
            ["A" 2] [{:ms "A", :s 2, :v 18}],
            ["A" 4] [{:ms "A", :s 4, :v 19}]}
           {["A" 1] [{:ms "A", :s 1, :v2 5}],
            ["A" 2] [{:ms "A", :s 2, :v2 8}],
            ["B" 4] [{:ms "B", :s 4, :v2 9}]}])

(map (partial apply merge) (vals (apply merge-with concat data)))
```

here's a step by step explaination:

first of all we merge all the toplevel maps, concatenating values for equal keys:

```
(apply merge-with concat data)
;;=> {["A" 1] ({:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15} {:ms "A", :s 1, :v2 5}), 
;;    ["A" 2] ({:ms "A", :s 2, :v 18} {:ms "A", :s 2, :v2 8}), 
;;    ["A" 4] [{:ms "A", :s 4, :v 19}], 
;;    ["B" 4] [{:ms "B", :s 4, :v2 9}]}
```

then for every value in the map we should perform the merge to one map:

```
(apply merge '({:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15} {:ms "A", :s 1, :v2 5}))
;;=> {:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15, :v2 5}
```

so we should use `map`:

```
(map (partial apply merge) (vals (apply merge-with concat data)))
;;=> ({:ms "A", :s 1, :v 15, :v2 5}
;;    {:ms "A", :s 2, :v 18, :v2 8}
;;    {:ms "A", :s 4, :v 19}
;;    {:ms "B", :s 4, :v2 9})
```